# Is it possible to reset sign-in cookies for all Gmail users in Google Admin?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

This can be done for individual users, but I would like to be able to force a weekly sign-in reset for all Gmail users in my organisation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Probably it should be moved to Server Fault - StackExchange site.

Comment: @Ruben Luckily for this question, this didn't happen.. Server Fault  score is more nuanced than the one sentence description says. E.g. managing a system by pushing buttons in a control panel is considered offtopic...

Comment: @NormalHuman AFAIK the way to achieve what the OP is looking for, can't be done by pushing buttons in a control panel. The administrator should use the administration API. The suggested tool in my answer is a command line tool based on the referred API

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the way to do that is through requiring users to change their password.

From [HowTo: Bulk "Require user to change password on next login"](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/kmW1elUPkuE)

> Hi All,
>
> If you decide to force a password change for all users you can use
>   [Dito GAM](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager) to flag all
>   the users for password change on next login:
>
> ```
> gam all users update user changepassword on
> ```
>
> Jay

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this would cause great unrest and I would have endless queries about forgotten passwords. Ideally I want to sign out the user, but keep their existing password.